# How you will sort 30gb file have 1 - 1000 numbers repetitively

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, large-files

I am having 30 gb file which is having just 1- 1000 numbers repetitively. I would like to know how to sort that file and you need to first load the file in the memory.

I had got through other links in SO but disagree on the point sorting it multiple chunks of files and keeping it in temp file. As I believe at the end of process I will be left with two large files (15 GB each) to sort. I can't load each to merge and sort.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you required to use merge sort? This can be done in linear time with a counting sort.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, there is no such requirement of using merge sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the values are all in the range 1..1000 you can do this with a simple version of [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

- Create an array of `counters[1000]` (1001 if your arrays are
  zero-based) all initialized to zero.
- Read the file, when you read value `n` from the file increment `counters[n]`.
- Now you know how many times each value appeared in the input file.
- Loop through `counters`, for each index `n` write `counters[n]` copies of `n` to output. For example, if `counters[100] == 5` then write `100` to output `5` times.

You don't need to hold the whole file in memory. You just need to count how many times each value appears in the file. That is sufficient information to create a sorted version of the original file.

Comment: This is the best you can do if you really need to sort the full list. If an approximation will do, you can sample instead and get an answer in sublinear time.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, Issue arises when I have to read the file - remember its 30gb

Comment: @AnilPurswani: You don't need to load the entire file into memory.  Just do a sequential read through the file,  updating the number  counts.  Then you can rewrite the file with the sorted values.